# MySQL n:m find elements from table one that ONLY have elements from table two

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: segments (id, name) and parts (id, name). These two have an n:m relationship, so segments can have multiple parts and a part can belong to several segments.

Of course we have a linking table segments_parts (segments_id, parts_id) to connect these two together, as is customary with n:m relationships.

Now, given a list of part ids I want to check if there is a segment that has exactly these parts, but NO MORE!

So, if for example segment 2 has parts 1 and 3 and segment 5 has parts 1, 3 and 7 when I request "give me the segment for parts 1 and 3" I want ONLY segment 2 to be returned, not both of them.

```
Segments                         Parts
------------------------         ------------------------
| ID | Name            |         | ID | Name            |
------------------------         ------------------------
| 1  | Segment 1       |         | 1  | Part 1          |
| 2  | Segment 2       |         | 2  | Part 2          |
| 3  | Segment 3       |         | 3  | Part 3          |
| 4  | Segment 4       |         | 4  | Part 4          |
| 5  | Segment 5       |         | 5  | Part 5          |
------------------------         | 6  | Part 6          |
                                 | 7  | Part 7          |
                                 ------------------------

segments_parts
------------------------
| segment_id | part_id |
------------------------
|     1      |     1   |
|     1      |     4   |
|     2      |     1   |
|     2      |     3   |
|     3      |     2   |
|     3      |     4   |
|     4      |     2   |
|     4      |     3   |
|     5      |     1   |
|     5      |     3   |
|     5      |     7   |
------------------------
```

Given input 1, 3 I want segment id 2 returned (as it is the segment that has these two part ids, and nothing else. Note that segment 5 ALSO has parts 1 and 3, but also has part 7 and therefore should not be returned!)

Given input 1,3,7 I want segment id 5 returned.

Given input 1, 6 I want nothing returned, since there is no segment that includes these two parts.

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. Well formatted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a set-within-sets query.  I like to solve these using `group by` and `having`.  Assuming no duplicates:

```
select sp.segment_id
from segments_parts sp
group by sp.segment_id
having <list size> = sum(sp.parts_id in (<your list here>)) and
       <list size> = count(*);
```

If you can have duplicates, then:

```
select sp.segment_id
from segments_parts sp
group by sp.segment_id
having <list size> = count(distinct case when parts_id in (<your list here> then parts_id end) and
       <list size> = count(distinct parts_id);
```

You need to add the length of the list in the `having` clause.

Comment: Wow, perfect... I'll give you the correct answer as soon as the site allows me to. :)

Comment: Ah, I spoke too soon ... apparently it's not working QUITE as I expected. I'll actually will have to add some sample data as jarlh requested, to make my case more clear. Stay tuned.

Comment: @Sorcy  . . . I was trying to use a shortcut.  You can fix the `having` clause by putting in the length of the list.